# SQL MAX not returning unique records

Tags: sql, select, max

I'm using the SQL MAX on a field in my db called "Date_Created", essentially i use it to bring back the most recent record for a particular user. It works fine for all user records that have higher count than 1 but when a user only has one record SQL MAX does not return a record" Can anyone advise what i'm doing wrong ?

code:

```
  "SELECT CP_Score.Credit_Score "
. "FROM CP_Score "
. "INNER JOIN phpro_users ON CP_Score.ID_No=phpro_users.ID_No "
. "WHERE phpro_users.User_ID = $userloggedin "
. "  AND CP_Score.Date_Created = (SELECT MAX(CP_Score.Date_Created) "
. "  FROM CP_Score)";
```

Comment: in that final select add in `WHERE CP_Score.ID_No = $userloggedin`

Comment: The sub-query needs a correlating condition, to make sure you get the max date for the main query CP_Score value.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CP_Score.Credit_Score
  FROM CP_Score
 INNER JOIN phpro_users ON CP_Score.ID_No=phpro_users.ID_No
 WHERE phpro_users.User_ID = $userloggedin
   AND CP_Score.Date_Created = (SELECT MAX(cps2.Date_Created)
                                  FROM CP_Score cps2 
                                 WHERE cps2.ID_No=phpro_users.ID_No)
```

Comment: Thanks all much appreciated. sadly still not working :(  Code was changed as follows: SELECT CP_Score.Credit_Score from CP_Score inner join phpro_users on CP_Score.ID_No=phpro_users.ID_No
where phpro_users.User_ID= $userloggedin
and CP_Score.Date_Created=(select MAX(CP_Score.Date_Created) from CP_Score where CP_Score.ID_No=phpro_users.User_ID)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for one record, you can limit the result set to a single record.  In ANSI/ISO standard syntax:

```
SELECT s.Credit_Score
FROM CP_Score s INNER JOIN
     phpro_users u
     ON s.ID_No = u.ID_No
WHERE u.User_ID = $userloggedin
ORDER BY Date_Created DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Some databases express the `FETCH FIRST` clause differently -- `SELECT TOP (1)` or `LIMIT` are common.